# SELENIUM - Error ElementNotInteractableException: Message: 0 - PYTHON

Tags: python, html, selenium

I am trying to click on button that will allow to me download a cdv in order to run daily checks, but the moment I tried to do it it thrown me an error like this

ElementNotInteractableException: Message:

this is my code:

import selenium

from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Safari()

driver.get('https://xxxxxxxxxx')

id_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='ap_email']")

## Send id information

id_box.send_keys('xxxxxx')

pass_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='ap_password']")

pass_box.send_keys('xxxxxxx')

## Find login button

login_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='signInSubmit']")

## Click login

login_button.click()

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME,"tours-controls__export")))

element.click()

I TRIED ALSO:

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(text(),'Export')]"))).click()

AND :

ele = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//body/div[@id='body-wrapper']/main[@id='main-wrapper']/div[@id='application']/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYbMP.png)/div[2]/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYbMP.png)/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYbMP.png)/div[2]/div[4]/span[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYbMP.png)/span[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYbMP.png)")

but still the same error.

Below the html:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYbMP.png)

Export

*when I click manually it change adding "disabled"*

Export

Answer (score 0):

> ElementNotInteractableException occurs when an element is found, but
> you can't be interacted with. For instance, you may not be able to
> click or send keys. This could happen due to various reasons like
> element being not visible or displayed, element is off screen or
> element is behind another element or hidden. So, you can perform some
> of the actions to make element interactable:

Check for overlays, check that element is displayed, (not in a "collapsed" or hidden state).

element_to_be_clickable doesn't mean it is actually "clickable" if you will. It checks some factors (non-zero size, not disabled, etc) but isn't a guarantee that the element will succeed a click.

Check to make sure the element is actually present on the rendered page.